# Self-Consistent solution of Boltzmann eqn. using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve Boltzmann eqn:

$\frac{e}{m}\tau\vec{E}_x\cdot \nabla_\vec{v}{f(\vec{v})}=f(\vec{v})-f_0(\vec{v})$

where

$f_0(v)=\exp{\frac{-m \vec{v}^2}{T}}$ and  $\vec{v}=\{\vec{v}_x,\vec{v}_y\}$ (i.e., $\vec{v}$ is in 2D.)

For simplicity, let's assume $\vec{v}_y=0$.  Assume $\tau$ and $T$ are constants. Then for any given $\vec{v}$ and $|E|$, $f_0(\vec{v})$ is completely known.

I am trying to set up a self-consistent code in Matlab to solve this equation for any given set of $\vec{v}$. However, I am not sure how to get Matlab to solve this? the ODE command, ode45, is not exactly for this task. Any ideas?

EDIT: I need to do a simulation, so I will choose the values of $\vec{v}$ and do the simulation accordingly. All other constants are assumed known ($e,m,\tau,T$ and $|E|$).

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! As posed, your question is unclear. Is everything given besides $v$? It looks like you'll need to solve a first order steady-state partial differential equation, in which case, you'll have to discretize your equation in one direction before using `ode45`. It's not clear that doing so is the best course of action; you might be better off discretizing both directions instead and solving the resulting nonlinear equations. I can't say what type of discretization would work best without knowing more about the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post. Yes everything is known, and the values of $\vec{v}$ is chosen by us to do a simulation. What is remaining is to do the self-consistent solution.

Answer (score 1):

To give background of the problem the general [Boltzmann Transport Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation) for electrons in an electric field is

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla_{\vec{r}} f - \frac{e}{m} \vec{E} \cdot \nabla_{\vec{v}}f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)_{\mathrm{coll}}$

where $f$ is the phase space velocity distribution function.  $f_0(\vec{v})$ is the steady state solution with no field (i.e. a maxwellian velocity distribution).

Then a (usually small) field is applied in one direction ($E_x$) which perturbs the velocity distribution of the electrons.  At this point, the distribution changes slightly, and if we apply steady state $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0\right)$and isotropic $\left(\nabla_{\vec{r}} f = 0\right) $  we are left with:

$\frac{e}{m} \vec{E} \cdot \nabla_{\vec{v}}f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)_{\mathrm{coll}}$

now we simply assume that $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)_{\mathrm{coll}}$ is proportional to the perturbation from equilibruim, $f(\vec{v}) - f_0(\vec{v})$, with a proportionality constant of $\frac{1}{\tau}$.  Defining the $x$ axis along the field gives the equation from the question:

$\frac{e}{m} \tau |E| \frac{d f(\vec{v})}{d v_x} = f(\vec{v}) - f_0(\vec{v})$

Now due to the steady state being isotropic and us defining the x direction along the field we get:

$\frac{e}{m} \tau |E| \frac{d f(v_x)}{d v_x} = f(v_x) - f_0(v_x)$

This form of the equation has an exact analytic solution (it is just a 1st order ODE).  Let

$a = \frac{e}{m} \tau |E|$

and the ODE becomes

$ f'(v_x) - \frac{1}{a} f(v_x) = - \frac{1}{a} f_0(v_x)$

which has a general solution:

$f(v_x) = C \exp(\frac{v_x}{a}) +\exp(\frac{v_x}{a}) \int_1^x - \frac{1}{a} \exp{\frac{\xi}{a}} f_0(\xi) \mathrm{d}\xi$

(shameless pulled from wolfram alpha at the moment)

I don't have my notes with me at the moment to make sure I have done this all exactly correctly, but I will update this tomorrow when I get to the office.  Im also fairly certain that the final equation simplifies but I can't remember how.

**EDIT:**

So I went back through my notes, and the problem I remembered from stat thermo had a few other small assumptions that don't apply in your question (it converted to energy as well).  Using wolframalpha and unity for the constants, I got an exact solution, although I am not happy with it (the inverse error function doesn't seem appropriate).

Even still, it should be possible to solve the above equation numerically as you originally asked using a standard finite difference formulation.  The boundary conditions should be that $f$ goes to 0 at both positive and negative infinity and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f dv_x = 1$.

Comment: I happen to use a slightly more in depth set of assumptions  for this exact equation in my research, so it was more for me practicing than anything.

Comment: The solution to the 1st order ODE will involve the error function, I wonder whether this is reasonable.

Comment: I added the analytic solution.  In about 12 hours I can go through my old notes and sort out where exactly this analysis ends up, but I am 95% certain that the point of assuming the collision term is proportional to the perturbation is that it can be solved exactly.

Comment: @student1 I have edited my post.  Apparently I slightly misremembered my previous problem and the assumptions it made.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, erfc(x) does not look appropriate here to me either. The problem in question clearly asks for a solution using self-consistency, for various electric fields (i.e. E is a variable, and so is v, so we get 3D plot).